# KeyNotFoundException at dictionary with string key

Tags: c#, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

I failed to get value with string key

```
...
Dictionary<string, Data> dateDic = new Dictionary<string, Data>();
...

public void GetDataList(string _code, int _startDate, int _limit, out List<Data> _list)
{
    _list = (from data in dateDic[_code].Values     // <= System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException!!!
            where data.date >= startDate
            orderby data.date descending
            select data).Take(_limit).ToList<Data>();
}
```

variable `_code` is `027410`

At watch window:

> stockShcodeDic[_code] System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException <= Error
>   stockShcodeDic["027410"]  {Base.Data} Base.Data   <= OK

Comment: are you sure there is only `027410`. the string may contain null character `\0` but it doesnt appear

Comment: You are using `dateDic` in code. Later you refer to `stockShcodeDic["027410"]`  being ok. Are those dictionaries the same?

Comment: Apparently the `_code` is missing in the dictionary. When you get an exception, try at Watch window `_code == "027410"`.

Comment: at watch window, code == "027410" is false i found my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is not present in the dictionary, you can handle it by using Dictionary.TryGetValue

```
List<Data> listValues; // Assuimging dateDic[_code].Values  is of type List<Data>
listValues = dateDic.TryGetValue(_code, out value);
_list  = listValues .where(x=>x.data.date >= startDate).orderby(data.date descending).Select(x=>x.data).ToList<Data>();;
```

or even simpler

```
public void GetDataList(string _code, int _startDate, int _limit, out List<Data> _list)
{
    if(dateDic.ContainsKey("_code"))
    {
      return;
    }
    _list = (from data in dateDic[_code].Values     // <= System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException!!!
            where data.date >= startDate
            orderby data.date descending
            select data).Take(_limit).ToList<Data>();
}
```